# How to access function parameters inside a promise

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have the following function:

```
var makeNewContextMenu = function( metadata, $toggle, $after){
    dataStore.getCollaboration(metadata._mountTarget).then(function(data){
      //need to access metadata, $toggle and $after inside promise
    })
}
```

How would I be able to access metadata, $toggle, and $after inside my promise?

Comment: You might want to read [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use them exactly as your code shows.  Variables or arguments from a parent scope are available to an inline function like your `.then()` handler.

```
var makeNewContextMenu = function( metadata, $toggle, $after){
    dataStore.getCollaboration(metadata._mountTarget).then(function(data){
       // this works!
       console.log(metadata);
       console.log($toggle);
       console.log($after);
    })
}
```

The only reason you might not be able to access a variable or argument defined in the parent scope is if some intervening scope defines a variable or argument of the same name.  In that case, the scope that is closer to you has precedence and the higher scoped variable is "hidden" by the closer scoped variable of the same name and the higher scoped variable would not be accessible without renaming one to not have the same name.  But, that is not what is happening in your case.

---

In your comment, you asked how to get a return value that includes `metadata`, `$toggle`, `$after` and `data`.  Because `dataStore.getCollaboration()` is asynchronous which means it's response is available sometime in the future, but `makeNewContextMenu()` returns immediately, you can't directly return `data` from `makeNewContextMenu()`.  But, you can return a promise and make the desired data be the fulfilled value of the promise like this:

```
var makeNewContextMenu = function( metadata, $toggle, $after){
    return dataStore.getCollaboration(metadata._mountTarget).then(function(data){
       return {
           metadata: metadata,
           $toggle: $toggle,
           $after: $after,
           data: data
       };
    })
}

makeNewContextMenu(...).then(function(info) {
    console.log(info.metadata);
    console.log(info.$toggle);
    console.log(info.$after);
    console.log(info.data);
});
```

Note, you really don't have to put `metadata`, `$toggle` and `$after` in this returned data structure because they were passed in as arguments to `makeNewContextMenu()` so they are already available in the scope in which `makeNewContextMenu()` was called.  You could just directly refer to them there and use their original variables.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick response. As a follow up question, how would I be able to return  {metadata, $toggle, $after, data} when I invoke makeNewContextMenu?

Comment: @user5844628 - Return them from what?

Comment: say I call, makeNewContextMenu. How would I be able to have makeNewContextMenu return {metadata, $toggle, $after, data}  as an output

Comment: @user5844628 - Assuming `dataStore.getCollaboration()` is asynchronous, you can't.  `data` is not available yet when `makeNewContextMenu()` returns.  It will return BEFORE `dataStore.getCollaboration()` has called its callback so `data` is not yet known.  You can return the promise and use the returns promise.  I will add how to do that to my answer.